# How many spaceman minifigure variations exist?

Tags: minifigures, space

I was looking at collecting all the different Spaceman minifigures.  So I'm wondering how many different types(styles) of Spaceman do exist.  Color variations is not necessarily but it would also be interesting to know that.

Note: Only astronauts (not robots & aliens)

So far I only have those three:

[image]

Comment: This would be a good question for a CW answer, as the list is managable but it's unlikely any single person would get them all.

Comment: Do you want astronauts, or everything including aliens and robots?

Comment: @Pubby8 Only astronauts (I'll edit the question)

Comment: I sometimes play with my Star Wars Clone Troopers as astronauts.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and also that you specify minifigs, but you may be interested to know there were maxifig astronauts in 1975's [set #367 Moon Landing](https://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/legoland/space/lego-367-1-moon-landing/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A full list of space related minifigures can be found on Bricklink [here](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=34) as well as under the [Town theme](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=67.330). If you count fantasy themes there are also many astronaut minifigures under Alien Conquest, Blacktron, Life on Mars, Mars Mission, Space Police, etc...

There is also the Spaceman from the 1st Collectible Minifigure series.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't thought about the town ones - good catch.

Comment: I can't find the Apollo figure in that list(site). Still looking...

Comment: @pcantin: That's under a the [Discovery theme](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=sp060)

Answer (score 3):

They also used the following helmet variation in Series 1 of the Minifigures set:

[image: Minifigures Series 1 Spaceman - Promo Graphic]

I also have the limited edition orange Lego Universe Spaceman that can be seen here:

[image: Lego Universe]

Neither of these came with backpacks.

There is also now the Minifigures "Galaxy Patrol" style spaceman which started appearing in Series 8:

[image: Minifigures Series 8 Galaxy Patrol - Promo Graphic]

This combined a new helmet with the much enhanced backpack/shoulder armour element.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you would include the Futuron Astronaut or Classic Space Astronaut in this list (image courtesy of http://www.toplessrobot.com/2009/05/the_30_greatest_lego_minifigs_of_all_time.php?page=2):

[image]
[image]

I had several of these as a kid - I remember black, blue, yellow, and red variants.